# What is the "correct" behavior for elements inside of a <button>?

Tags: html, w3c

I was trying to fix a bug where a file input inside of a `button` element was not working properly on Firefox/IE. The `<input>` was being made extremely large with its opacity set to 0 which allowed whoever wrote the markup to create a custom-styled "Browse" button.

This worked just fine in Chrome, Safari, and Opera (which all happen to be running Webkit/Blink). Clicking on the button would transparently click on the "Browse..." button from the nested `<input>`, but Firefox and IE had different behaviors. I fixed this issue by just making the input hidden and not a child of the button, then calling its `click` event when the button is clicked.

This had me curious though and I put together some tests to see what works and what doesn't: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EaPyp/13/).

(If the fiddle ever happens to go away, here are the contents:

HTML:

```
<button>
    <label for="checkbox-input">Click me</label>
    <input id="checkbox-input" type="checkbox"/>
</button>

<button>
    <input type="text"/>
</button>

<button>
    <input type="color"/>
</button>

<button>
    <a href="#test">test</a>
</button>
<button>
    <span id="clicky">testing!</span>
</button>
<button>
    <span class="crosshair">testing!</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 100;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.crosshair {
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#clicky').on('click', function() {
    alert('clicky');
});
```

It seems as though in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, all click through the button and trigger the click event on both the button and nested element. Firefox only clicks the button. IE only clicks the button, but displays the `cursor` when hovering over the nested element.

Allowed content for a button according to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html):

> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

The `input` element falls under both phrasing and interactive content. Based off of this information, do any of these browsers display correct behavior?

Comment: Explicitly violating the specification (putting interactive content in where there is no interactive content allowed) and then expecting "correct" behaviour is... weird.

Comment: Not just weird.  If you violate the spec, all bets are off.  Correct is not defined for that case.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol what would make an `input` element non-interactive then?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" />` would be non-interactive, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an `INPUT` element inside a `BUTTON`. Your HTML is broken. There is no way to determine if any of the browsers behave correctly or not.